# What is the difference when using ensure and else after rescue?

Tags: ruby, rescue

1. What is the difference between using `ensure`:

   ```
   begin
     foo_process
   rescue
     bar_process
   ensure
     baz_process
   end
   ```

   and putting the process after the `begin` ... `rescue` ... `end` block?

   ```
   begin
     foo_process
   rescue
     bar_process
   end
   baz_process
   ```
2. What is the difference between using `else`:

   ```
   begin
     foo_process
   rescue
     bar_process
   else
     baz_process
   end
   ```

   and continuing that process before `rescue` (supposing that `baz_process` does not raise an error)?

   ```
   begin
     foo_process
     baz_process
   rescue
     bar_process
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1.

Using `ensure`, `baz_process` is alway executed even though `foo_process` throw exception, return from method.

For example,

```
def foo_process
  puts 'foo_process'
  return 111
end

def f1
  begin
    return foo_process
  rescue 
    puts 'bar_process'
  ensure 
    puts 'baz_process'
  end
end

def f2
  begin
    return foo_process
  rescue 
    puts 'bar_process'
  end
  puts 'baz_process'
end

>> f1
foo_process
baz_process
=> 111
>> f2
foo_process
=> 111
```

Comment: I am not clear about the execution order. Does the `ensure` block cut in before executing `return`?

Comment: @sawa, To make it clear, I modified the code. `ensure` block is executed just before return to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, using `ensure`, `baz_process` will always be run, even if an exception is not caught by the `rescue` block (i.e. in your example code, even if the exception is not a `StandardError`). It will also be run if `bar_process` raises an exception. Neither of these things are true for code placed after the `begin...rescue...ensure` block.

For question 2, the difference is that exceptions thrown by code in the `else` block are not rescued. This is more relevant when there is also an ensure block, as the code will run before it.

Comment: @sawa: Yes, sorry I missed the supposition, but it is a little confusing to make that a requirement (A bit like saying why use branch condition `if x > y` under the assumption x is always greater than y). I could assert that none of the code raises an error, in which case all the variations are equivalent. In part the *point* of the difference when using `else` in a `begin...rescue...ensure` sequence is that you wish to control which parts of code have errors managed.